# Forecast on a date-based dataset in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, forecasting, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to perform a forecast of body weight values based on data acquired periodically. Here is the dataset specification:

```
DATE (X-Axis)
01/01/2015
01/02/2015
01/03/2015
01/04/2015

BODY WEIGHT (Y-Axis)
90.3
89.8
87.3
88.6
```

I would like to be able to forecast the weight value at a specific date in the future (let's say 01/01/2016) with the forecast value becoming more precise while I keep on feeding the dataset with additional values over the time.

How can I achieve this in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: I would suppose that those dates are DMY format (e.g. first of each month).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common [FORECAST function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/FORECAST-function-50CA49C9-7B40-4892-94E4-7AD38BBEDA99) should be able to do this.

```
=forecast(C2, A$8:A$11, A$2:A$5)
```

The documentation link provided is Excel based but the syntax is identical. I cannot unequivocally  state the same for the algorithm.

[image: forecast_weight]